# After upgrading to IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 all my projects stopped loading in it - directory structure is completely gone

Tags: intellij-idea

Yesterday, I upgraded my `IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition)` to the 2022.3.1 (Build #IC-223.8214.52, built on December 20, 2022) version. All the folders, files and an entire directory structure is gone, leaving only `pom.xml`.

[image]

I've tried closing and re-opening the project 10 times, but it didn't help.

I've also tried invalidating all the cache - didn't help as well.

Any help?

Btw, IntelliJ IDEA gets worse and worse in the course of last few years, and I know plenty of people around saying the same.

Comment: Have you tried to run "Reload" from Maven tool window? Also you may try to remove IDE related data (.iml file and .idea folder) and reimport project.

Comment: @y.bedrov I've tried reloading Maven project - w/o any success; and then I just did what you wrote - removed IntelliJ IDEA related data and re-created IntelliJ IDEA project.. but the latter is super inconvenient to do with all the projects you may have.

Comment: Do you face it with every project?

Comment: @y.bedrov initially - yes, then I removed IntelliJ related files/folders and recreated projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try **File > Invalidate caches... >** Check the first checkbox **> Invalidate and Restart**.
[image]

Comment: I did this. Didn't help.